# Which Java OTR library should I choose?

Tags: java, encryption, off-the-record-messaging

I want to add [OTR (Off the record) Messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging) into my (XMPP) chat application, which is written in java. A quick google search showed at least two possible libraries:

- java-otr: http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/index.php#downloads
  that is the one gibberbot uses, last change Oct 2009
- otr4j: http://code.google.com/p/otr4j/ - last change Aug 2010

**Short question:** Which one should I choose?

Long question: The library should of course provide a decent level of interoperability, so that the OTR messaging works with the various XMPP client that are out there. Also some pros/cons of the library you suggest would be nice. Basically everything that could be interesting for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the original from [cypherpunks](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/index.php#downloads) which seemed to be the way to go a few years ago, there is also a maintained version at https://github.com/otr4j/otr4j (See [Hans-Christoph Steiner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161301/which-java-otr-library-should-i-choose/11692461?noredirect=1#comment61810699_11692461)).

Comment: At this point, the best maintained is https://github.com/otr4j/otr4j  It combines the work from the Cypherpunks' java-otr, jitsi/otr4j, redsolution/otr4j, and guardianproject/otr4j.

Comment: Can this library be used with Xmpp(openfire) server?
Also, how to use OTR4j in an android project?